# Use sendgrid from send emails with nodemailer appication gives following error?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

use nodemailer and nodemailer-sendgrid-transport it show the following error

**error:The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements**

```
`const nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
 const sendGridTranspoter=require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport')

 const transport=nodemailer.createTransport(sendGridTranspoter({

 service: 'SendGrid',

 auth:{
      api_user:'myuser name',
      api_key:'password'
   }));
```

`

this is inside my sign up controller function

```
     var email = {
                from: 'sener  email',
                to: 'receiver valid email',
                subject: 'shopMe',
                text: 'successfully sign up',
                html: '<b>Hello world</b>'
              };

            transport.sendMail (email, function(err, info){
                if (err ){
                  console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                  console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two possible ways,
 1.allow less secure apps "on" in your google mail security
 2.Go to  sendgrid, click on marketing and after click senders , fillup the details and check it

Comment: the first method seems to be invalid since google now doesn't allow us to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to verify the mail that is the sender. I solved this problem in this way:

Go here:
**Setting** -> **Sender Authentication** -> **Single Sender Verification** -> **Verify an Address**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIMoP.png)

After that, fill out the form on the right and complete the verification of the sender's mail.

[You can read in more detail here.](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/)

Comment: Settings are meant here: [https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth)